# Need help with Task assigning and rewarding as currency which withdrawable

Tags: plugins, user-roles, dashboard, membership

I have created custom roles and registration forms by using ultimate member plugin.

1. Mr. Y
2. Mr. X

I've assigned Mr. Y to my purchasable services (I am using ez form calculator plugin for this).

Now the problem is with Mr. X
How to assign task which submit by Mr. Y to Mr. X?
How can Mr. X earn some rewards as real currency (lets say $5 which withdrawable by PayPal) by completing his task?

Comment: Is this functionality that the Ultimate Member plugin provides? You'd have to ask them. Or is this entirely new functionality that you'd like to write?

Comment: new functionality